# Update query is causing a crash in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

i am trying to write a function that takes 2 indexes as argument and takes value from a table with that indexes. With theese values code must update the same table. Basicly database updating from DataGridview.

nothing worked so i commented out the SQL line and make it very very simple. But here is another problem. it just crashes with this --> "'[13680] WindowsApp2.exe' program exited with the code -1073740940 (0xc0000374)." (i translate it to English)

tried everything please help. The database i am querying is on Ms Access by the way.

```
Private Function Update_Notes(rowIndex As Integer, colIndex As Integer)
        If Environment.UserName = DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex).Cells.Item(1).Value.ToString() Then
        'Get the values
        con.Open()
        Dim hakedKod As String
        Dim ddate As Date
        Dim note As String
        Dim updateNoteId As Long
        hakedKod = DataGridView2.Item(1, rowIndex).Value
        ddate = DataGridView2.Item(2, rowIndex).Value
        note = DataGridView2.Item(3, rowIndex).Value.ToString
        updateNoteId = DataGridView2.Item(0, rowIndex).Value

        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "UPDATE TBL_Notes SET [Not]='12aa' WHERE [Kimlik] = 28"

        '@hakedKod, [Tarih] = @ddate, [Not] = @note WHERE [Kimlik] = @id"

        'initialize parameters for sterilization and date error stuff
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", updateNoteId)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hakedkod", hakedKod)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddate", ddate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", note)

        cmd.CommandText = sql

        Dim i As Integer
        Try
            i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            DataGridView2_Loader()
        End Try
        con.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("maalesef kayıt için değişiklik yetkiniz bulunmamaktadır.")
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I realize you have it in [], but "not" is a reserved word.  Can you rename that column to see if it fixes the problem?

Comment: You have a debugger. Use it to debug rather than running the compiled exe.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with the parametrization. Without the [Kimlik]=@id i can run the application. why is it a problem?

Comment: Because you are [using `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)? Are you sure the database type of the id is `Int64`, as opposed to `Int32`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions have a return type and include the keyword `Return` followed by the value you wish to return.

I don't like huge `If` blocks so I negated it and returned to the calling code.

Connections should be declared in the method where they are used. They must be disposed and also commands need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks take care of this closing and disposing even if there is an error.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute...`.

Your `CommandText` only contains literals; no parameter names so the parameters values are never reflected in the execute.

I had to guess at the datatypes of the parameters. Check your database. I also had to guess at the name of the hakedkod column. The closest I came with Google Translate was minced meat. :-)

Access pays no attention to parameter names. They are only interested in the position. The position of the parameter in the sql string must match the order the parameters are added to the parameters collection.

```
Private ConnStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Function Update_Notes(rowIndex As Integer, colIndex As Integer) As Integer
    If Environment.UserName <> DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).RowIndex).Cells.Item(1).Value.ToString() Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sql = "UPDATE TBL_Notes SET [Hak] = @hakedkod, [Tarih] = @ddate, [Not]= @note WHERE [Kimlik] = @id"
    Using con As New OleDbConnection(ConnStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@hakedkod", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView2.Item(1, rowIndex).Value.ToString
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ddate", OleDbType.Date).Value = CDate(DataGridView2.Item(2, rowIndex).Value)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DataGridView2.Item(3, rowIndex).Value.ToString
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(DataGridView2.Item(0, rowIndex).Value)
        con.Open()
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return i
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim retVal As Integer
    Try
        retVal = Update_Notes(row, col)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    If retVal > 0 Then
        DataGridView2_Loader()
    Else
        MsgBox("maalesef kayıt için değişiklik yetkiniz bulunmamaktadır.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. you have opened my eyes about the connections as well. Thank you for the extra help and free lesson. i have lot to learn.